# Unable to add GridViewRow in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I'm trying to add a gridviewrow as a subtotal in the below mentioned code and it doesn't allow me to add it in this line in `AddTotalRow` method. It says below error.

`gvData.Rows.Add(row);`

[image]

```
    string currentYear = string.Empty;
    int subTotal, subTotalCompleted = 0;
    int subTotalRowIndex = 0;

    protected void OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        subTotal = 0;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataTable dt = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).DataView.Table;
            string year = dt.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["year"].ToString();
            if (year != currentYear)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowIndex > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = subTotalRowIndex; i < e.Row.RowIndex; i++)
                    {
                        subTotal += Convert.ToInt32(gvData.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text);
                        subTotalCompleted += Convert.ToInt32(gvData.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text);
                    }
                    this.AddTotalRow("Sub Total", subTotal.ToString("C2"), subTotalCompleted.ToString("C2"));
                    subTotalRowIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;
                }
                currentYear = year;
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddTotalRow(string labelText, string value, string completed)
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F9F9F9");
        row.Cells.AddRange(new TableCell[4] {
                           new TableCell(),
                           new TableCell{ Text = labelText, HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right },
                           HyperLinkCell(value, "http://www.yahoo.com"),
                           HyperLinkCell(completed, "http://www.google.com")});
        gvData.Controls[0].Controls.Add(row);
    }

    protected TableCell HyperLinkCell(string text, string url)
    {
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
        try
        {
            link.Text = text;
            link.Font.Underline = true;
            link.Target = "_blank";
            link.NavigateUrl = url;
            link.Attributes.Add("style", "color:Black;");
            cell.Controls.Add(link);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return cell;
    }

    protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = subTotalRowIndex; i < gvData.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            subTotal += Convert.ToInt32(gvData.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text);
            subTotalCompleted += Convert.ToInt32(gvData.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text);
        }
        this.AddTotalRow("Sub Total", subTotal.ToString("C2"), subTotalCompleted.ToString("C2"));
    }
```

Can someone help me to rectify this?

**Update 1:**

Subtotal for column completed and its 2nd subtotal is summing up first subtotal which shouldn't happen.

Completed subtotal has 1,998.00 and instead it should be 1411.00. Please find the below pic for reference.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `gridview1.DataSource`

Comment: @Saadi - I haven't tried, can you please explain how this can be achieved?

Comment: Can you share how you are loading data into the grid view? And also the business use case of what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - I am trying to do exactly what is present in this link https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-SubTotal-and-Grand-Total-in-ASPNet-GridView.aspx. On top of this I need to add hyperlink to subtotal rows.

Comment: What happened when you did `gvData.Controls[0].Controls.Add(row);`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - Thanks! It worked.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - I'm facing few issues in my last step and updated my post with `Update1` and latest code. Can you please provide your thoughts.

Comment: You need to debug your code and check what happens in `OnDataBound` method and how `subTotal` and `subTotalCompleted` ends up in wrong value.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - Also how can I align the hyperlink to the right of the table cell.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - I tried debugging and when it comes to OnDataBound its already has first subtotal value. `subTotal`is fine and only `subTotalCompleted` is having issues.

Comment: `Also how can I align the hyperlink to the right of the table cell` try some googling and use some of the suggested approach there. And let us know if you are facing any specific issue there..

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - I got the solution for alignment, but couldn't find the issue happening in `OnDataBound` for subtotal.